# Autoresponder with rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, auto-responder

How do I implement email autoresponder in ruby on rails 3.2.x ? I've made some research with Google and I found this one : [dram.rubyforge.org/](http://dram.rubyforge.org/). The snag is that, the gem seems to be not released yet.

Has anyone any clue for this ?

Answer (score 1):

There is another gem called [Faucet](https://github.com/dshipper/Faucet) that might be useful.

Currently it only supports Rails 3.1 since Dan Shipper (the author) hasn't updated it in awhile, but I'm probably going to issue a pull request soon since I'm tweaking it for a project of mine on Rails 3.2.

Answer (score 1):

The [mailman](https://github.com/titanous/mailman) gem might also work for you. It is a simple gem for polling an email account and it has a pretty easy set up process.

Best of all, there is a [Railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/313-receiving-email-with-mailman) that walks you through it. You need Railscast pro account to view the video but if you don't a subscription you can still view the code for the episode on [github](https://github.com/railscasts/313-receiving-email-with-mailman).